# CSS element not showing over image

Tags: html, css

I bet this is probably something stupid, I am trying put an absolute element over an image, but its not appearing.

```
<div class="circle" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 100px;"></div>

                    <img src="images/madison-siteplan.png" class="siteplan" />
```

here is the attentional css for the circle:

```
.circle {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            color: red;
            }
```

Comment: is the parent element set to `position:relative`? also, you probably want to use `background-color` rather than `color`

Comment: Build a fiddle to demonstrate.  As a side-note, if the circle is first, and the image is second, then you'll need to use `z-index`.  And remember, `z-index` only works when the elements have position other than static (meaning position relative, fixed, or absolute)

Comment: As noted both above and below, changing `color` to `background-color` will fix your problem.

Comment: Give some visual property, AND change the order of your elements... (check my answer with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the absolutely positioned element to be **after** the image. Give that element some visual properties so you can see it... (border, background-color, text...)

```css
#bla {
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/500">
<div id="bla"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It has no border or outline, so the edge won't show up.

It has no background colour, so it is transparent.

It has no content inside it, so the foreground colour has no practical effect.

Change any one of the above.

Answer (score 1):

@Quentin is right, I just read his answer, but since I already made a snippet, I add it here. (I only added a background-color to the original code, apart from moving the inline CSS to the external CSS rule):

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="circle"> </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="siteplan" />
```